# How to find particular file in all subfolders in unix

Tags: shell, unix

I trying to find a particular find in unix using  "find . filename". But the files are in subfolder and it is showing me lots of other files and location. I just want to see the exact location of my file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**find . -name "name_of_the_file"**

*Example*

Let us say I want to search files with the name "main.yml" inside my current directory (.)

```
user@host123:~/prom$ find . -name "main.yml"
./node_exporter/tasks/main.yml
./node_exporter/vars/main.yml
./exporter_exporter/tasks/main.yml
./exporter_exporter/vars/main.yml
```